How to define double factorial for non positive integers?
I studied double factorial which known for natural number
$$ n!!=n(n-2)!! , 1!!=0!!=1$$
So we have for $n\in N$
$$ (2n)!!=2^n n! , (2n+1)!!=\frac{(2n+1)!}{2^n n!}$$
but I found on Math-World formula for $z\in C$
$$z!!=2^{\frac{z}{2}} \Gamma\left(\frac{z}{2}+1 \right) \left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{\frac{\cos(\pi z)-1}{4}} $$
I tried to find why it used this formula
I think we can write formula of double factorial for natural numbers by
$$ z!!=2^{\frac{z}{2}} \Gamma\left(\frac{z}{2}+1 \right) \left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}f(z)}$$
where
$$f(z) = \begin{cases} 0 &\mathrm{if} \space z \space \mathrm{is\space even} \\ -1  & \mathrm{if} \space z \space \mathrm{is\space odd} \end{cases}$$
which mean
$$ f(z)=\frac{(-1)^z-1}{2}$$
but since $(-1)^z=\cos(\pi z)$ So I think it used that to define double factorial for non positive integers (which is correct for natural numbers).
but by the same way we can find that
$$ z!!=2^{\frac{z}{2}} \Gamma\left(\frac{z}{2}+1 \right) \frac{2^{-\frac{f(z)}{2}}}{\Gamma\left(1+\frac{f(z)}{2}\right)}$$
where $f(z)$ is $0$ if $z$ is even and is $-1$ if its odd which mean
$$ z!!=2^{\frac{z}{2}} \Gamma\left(\frac{z}{2}+1 \right) \frac{2^{\frac{1-\cos(\pi z)}{4}}}{\Gamma\left(\frac{\cos(\pi z)+3}{4}\right)}$$
the last formula is also correct for all natural numbers.
My Question is why math world chose that formula ?
is my reason is correct ? or there are another reason for choosing that formula?

See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial#Generalizations

Start by expressing the double factorials of integers via half-shift gamma functions.

@Gary does that explain that formula ? show your work please .
